# How to validate a CSS span class in XML on Oxygen Program?

Tags: css, xml, oxygenxml

related to my first question.  The CSS span class will not validate in XML.

```
 <l rend="indent"> <span class="face_dropcap_ ">C</span><hi rend="initial_roman">E</hi>stoit alors que le prefent des <span class=".face_cap">D</span>ieux</l>
```

CSS code:

```
.face_dropcap_ {
font-size: 3em; 
font-family: Palatino,serif;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 100%;
float: left; 
margin-right: 5px; 
text-align: center;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
/*face_cap style is for the capital letters that are non-italic in the body of the poem*/
.face_cap_{font-size: 3em; 
font-family: Palatino,serif;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 100%;
float: left; 
margin-right: 5px; 
text-align: center;
font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: Please link your first question, tell us what you are trying to do and what goes wrong.  Also post the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have a dot in the value of the class...

```
<span class=".face_cap">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the <l> element seems not to be defined anymore in the XHTML 5 specification: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/